# Expanding behavior of Richfaces Collapsible Panel

Tags: jsf-2, richfaces

So, I have recently started working on a JSF page using richfaces 4, in which I have a **rich:collapsiblePanel**. I face a problem however, I am using the collapsiblePanel within a **rich:dataGrid**, which renders the collapsiblePanels by iterating though a list recieved from the server. There is a link to 'sort' the collapsiblePanels according to the data in the panel header (in the backing bean of course). When any of the collapsiblePanels are expanded, and the sort link is clicked, all of them are expanded, whilst all are expanded, if one is closed, and the link clicked again, all of them close.

Things I have tried:

- Changing the switchType to any other than **client** (i.e ajax and server)
- Adding a constant **boolean** in the backing bean to force the expand attribute to false on reload (although it is not even affected by the backing bean at all)

Sample code of what it looks like at the moment:

```html
<h:panelGrid id="SomePanelGrid">
     <rich:dataGrid id="SomeDataGrid" value="bean.listValues" var="values"
         iterationStatusVar="counter" elements="10">

          <rich:collapsiblePanel switchType="client" expanded="#{bean.expanded}">
               Layouts and what not (not in relation to this)
          </rich:collapsiblePanel>
     </rich:dataGrid>
</h:panelGrid>
```

The link simply calls a method in the backing bean which does the sorting.

I have found a similar problem, involving a dataTable instead of a dataGrid, although no answers have been given, but only links that lead to more dead ends. This can be found at: https://community.jboss.org/message/819938

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Unfortunately I do not have alot of time to answer alot of other questions at the moment, but I will be checking back a bit later.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have many syntax flaws inside your code, here is how it should looks like :

```
<h:panelGrid id="SomePanelGrid">
    <rich:dataGrid id="SomeDataGrid" value="#{bean.listValues}" var="values"
            iterationStatusVar="counter" elements="10">

        <rich:collapsiblePanel switchType="client" expanded="#{bean.expanded}">
            Layouts and what not (not in relation to this)
        </rich:collapsiblePanel>
    </rich:dataGrid>
</h:panelGrid>
```

You are probably experiencing only **one** collapsiblePanel in your example, this code modified and tested work properly.

Now if you want to save collapsiblePanels expanded state when refreshing your dataGrid by AJAX, you need to add some stuff.

**First**, you need to add one property to your objects you are iterating on, to save the state of **each** panels.

```
public class Item
{
    private boolean expanded;

    public void setExpanded(boolean expanded)
    {
        this.exanded = expanded;
    }

    public boolean getExpanded()
    {
        return this.expanded;
    }

    // Your other stuff
}
```

**Second**, you need to add a listener in your bean to know when user changes the state of a panel, note the attribute to get back which item is related to this panel.

```
@ManagedBean
@ViewScope
public class Bean
{
    private List<Item> listValues;

    @PostConstruct
    void init()
    {
        listValues = //... Some initialization to your list
    }

    public List<Item> getListValues()
    {
        return this.listValues;
    }

    public void toggle(PanelToggleEvent event)
    {
        // Take the current item
        Item item = (Item)event.getComponent().getAttributes().get("item");

        // Save the current state in the item
        item.setExpanded(event.getExpanded());
    }
}
```

**Finally**, you need to change your `switchType` to AJAX and add the listener in your code without forgetting the attribute that need to be passed in the listener.

```
<h:form>
    <rich:dataGrid id="SomeDataGrid" value="#{bean.listValues}" var="item"
            iterationStatusVar="counter" elements="10">

        <rich:collapsiblePanel switchType="ajax" expanded="#{item.expanded}">
            <f:attribute name="item" value="#{item}" />

            Layouts and what not (not in relation to this)
        </rich:collapsiblePanel>
    </rich:dataGrid>
</h:form>
```

Comment: Should anyone experience problems with this solution because the listener does not work correctly, check out this problem here: https://issues.jboss.org/browse/RF-11568